# A variable was not declared in this scope c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, parameters, scope

I have to do this program for Uni and I keep getting this "variable was not declared in this scope" error. This is the assignment :

> Write a function that takes a string and an integer array as a parameter and returns a string, in which each character in the string parameter according to the corresponding value in the integer Array is multiplied. You can assume that (apart from the terminating null /0 character of the string ) both arrays have the same number of elements .Furthermore, the function should return in a reference parameters the extra number of characters from your result.
>   Exemple Parameter 1 "abcd" {1,2,3,4}
>   Result : "abbcccdddd" 6

This is the code I've managed to write so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string Function (string c, int numbers[n])
{
    string result;
    for ( int i=0; i< n;i++)
    {
        int index= numbers[i];
        for (int j=0; j< index;j++)
        {
            result.append(c.at(i));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main ()
{
    int n;
    string r;
    cout << "Nr in array";
    cin >> n;
    int numbers [n];
    for ( int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        cout << "Nr";
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    string c;
    cout << " Write some letters";
    cin >> c;
    r=Function(c,numbers[n]);
    cout << r;
    return 0;   
}
```

And these are the errors that pop up when I try to compile my code:

```
4:40: error: 'n' was not declared in this scope
In function 'std::string Function(...)':
7:20: error: 'n' was not declared in this scope
9:14: error: 'numbers' was not declared in this scope
12:18: error: 'c' was not declared in this scope
In function 'int main()':
33:25: error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'std::string {aka class std::basic_string<char>}' through '...'
```

I know this may be a trivial solution, and I've searched for similar problems on stackoverflow before posting this, but nothing really came close to my problem, I think. I mean, I don't define my function after the main function, or define my variables inside loops and then call them outside of that. Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: `string Function (string c, int numbers[n])` what is that `n`?

Comment: This is where using `std::vector` would eliminate a lot of mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass array length to the function because you know that the string and array have the same length.
Also you can't do this in C++: `cin >> n; int numbers [n];` because n is not const expression. You can use `int *numbers=new int[n];` instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string Function (const string &c, int* numbers)
{
    string result;
    for (size_t i=0; i<c.size(); i++)
        result.append(numbers[i],c.at(i));
    return result;
}

int main ()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Nr in array: ";
    cin >> n;
    int *numbers=new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Nr: ";
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    string c;
    cout << "Write some letters: ";
    cin >> c;
    cout << Function(c,numbers) << endl;
    delete[] numbers;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax you are using to pass the array is not valid. You should pass the pointer (which is what the array actually is) as well as it's length as a separate parameter.

Moreover, when allocating arrays the way you did, you need to know about the size of arrays in advance as you cannot decide this during run-time. That is what dynamic memory allocations with `new` are for, as below. Remember to always free allocated memory to make sure there is no memory leak.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// numbers is a pointer and n is the length of it
string Function (string c, int* numbers, int n)
{
    string result;
    for ( int i=0; i< n;i++)
    {
        int index= numbers[i];
        for (int j=0; j< index;j++)
        {
            result += c.at(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main ()
{
    int n;
    string r;
    cout << "Nr in array";
    cin >> n;

    // allocate dynamic memory in desired size
    int* numbers = new int[n];

    for ( int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        cout << "Nr";
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    string c;
    cout << " Write some letters";
    cin >> c;
    r=Function(c,numbers, n);
    cout << r;

    // free previously allocated memory
    delete[] numbers;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also i don't think variable length arrays are supported by C++.

Comment: @bkVnet C has always supported them, and the same with C++. A pointer acts like an array.

Comment: @tadman are you sure? I mean is this a standard behaviour or a compiler extension? this code doesn't complie for me although I'm using a pre-C++ 11 compiler. I am referring to the `cin >> n; int numbers [n];` code.

Comment: @bkVnet Yes, you are right. I forgot to check if rest of the code actually compiled (sorry). The way the memory was allocated in the line you are referring to was wrong, as the value of `n` was not available during stack generation (:

Comment: @tadman In fact, there are no VLAs even in C++14. (But they exist in C starting from C99.) g++ with `-pedantic-errors` rejects them, and following page says that they are supported only as an extension: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I mean traditional C-style arrays which are not fixed size and therefore are inherently "variable": `int *c` or `int c[]`. It's up to the programmer to respect any boundaries that may be present, hence methods with signatures like `int *ary, size_t size`. That's why using a Standard Library container is a better plan, like `std::vector`.

Comment: @tadman You're right, pointers in both languages work almost exactly in a same way and they allow to create arrays of dynamic size. But the term VLA means something like `cin >> n; int numbers [n];`. In other words, an *array* declaration in which size is not a compile-time constant. *This* thing does not exist in standard C++, that's why bkVnet asked to remove it from the code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat All a matter of terminology here. `argv[]` is considered "variable length" in a sense, but not in the sense of the array itself being dynamically resizable. C++ has specific variable length arrays, but notes you note with that signature.